# Is it possible to plot iGraph plots on cygwin?

Tags: python, plot, cygwin, igraph

While having no problems producing `iGraph` plots on *Ubuntu,* I get the following errors on *cygwin:*

```
$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 28 2014, 01:34:03)
[GCC 4.8.3] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from igraph import Graph, plot
>>>
>>> g = Graph([(0,1), (0,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,2), (2,5), (5,0), (6,3), (5,6)])
>>> g.vs["name"] = ["Alice", "Bob", "Claire", "Dennis", "Esther", "Frank", "George"]
>>>
>>> layout = g.layout("kk")
>>> plot(g, layout = layout)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/drawing/__init__.py", line 475, in plot
    result.show()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/drawing/__init__.py", line 327, in show
    "on this platform: %s" % plat)
NotImplementedError: showing plots is not implemented on this platform: CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW
>>>
```

### Did anyone succeeded in producing `iGraph` plots on *cygwin?*

EDIT:
The [documentation](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.drawing-module.html) states:

> Plotting is dependent on the pycairo library which provides Python
>   bindings to the popular Cairo library. This means that if you don't
>   have pycairo installed, you won't be able to use the plotting
>   capabilities.

I'll check if something is wrong with my `py2cairo` install.

---

Note that other `iGraph` functionality works just fine on *cygwin:*

```
$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 28 2014, 01:34:03)
[GCC 4.8.3] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from igraph import Graph, plot
>>> g = Graph()
>>> print(g)
IGRAPH U--- 0 0 --
>>> g = Graph([(0,1), (0,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,2), (2,5), (5,0), (6,3), (5,6)])
>>> g.vs["name"] = ["Alice", "Bob", "Claire", "Dennis", "Esther", "Frank", "George"]
>>> g.vs["age"] = [25, 31, 18, 47, 22, 23, 50]
>>> g.vs["gender"] = ["f", "m", "f", "m", "f", "m", "m"]
>>> g.es["is_formal"] = [False, False, True, True, True, False, True, False, False]
>>> g.es[0]["is_formal"] = True
>>> g.es[0]
igraph.Edge(<igraph.Graph object at 0xffcb542c>, 0, {'is_formal': True})
>>> g["date"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'Attribute does not exist'
>>> g["date"] = "2015-05-31"
>>> g["date"]
'2015-05-31'
>>> g.degree()
[3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2]
>>> g.edge_betweenness()
[6.0, 6.0, 4.0, 2.0, 4.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 4.0]
>>> g.vs[2].degree()
4
>>>
```

**Environment:**

- Windows 7
- Cygwin CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW Ron 2.0.1(0.287/5/3)
- iGraph 0.7.1

Answer (score 0):

There's probably nothing wrong with `py2cairo` on your machine, but you can test it yourself. Try `plot(g, "test.png", layout=layout)` - this would save the plot into a file instead of showing it. The error message you see is thrown by igraph because it is not able to figure out how to instruct the operating system to display a PNG file (into which the plot was saved) in a window.

The command that is used to show plots is stored in a configuration variable named `apps.image_viewer`. You can alter it as follows:

```
>>> from igraph import Configuration
>>> cfg = Configuration.instance()
>>> cfg["apps.image_viewer"] = "start"
```

This will probably do the trick as the `start` command on Windows is supposed to open the default image viewer if you pass the name of a PNG file to it. If it works, you can persist the changes by writing the following to the file pointed to by `cfg.filename`:

```
[apps]
image_viewer=start
```

For what it's worth, the part of igraph that is supposed to figure out which image viewer to use on a particular OS (if the `apps.image_viewer` key is not present) is in `igraph/configuration.py` in a function named `get_platform_image_viewer()`. This function uses `platform.system()` to determine which OS you are using. If you could let me know what `platform.system()` prints in your Python, I'll submit a patch that makes igraph treat Cygwin the same way as Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, @Tamás. I'll check its various suggestions presently. On my cygwin: `platform.system() == CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW` (also what the `NotImplementedError` exception reports).

Comment: As for the other suggestions, @Tamás - saving the PNG to file works. However, I couldn't coax `windows image viewer` to display from cygwin. I'm reinstalling my `X11` now, and see if I can display using `ImageMagick`. That patch you mention would be appreciated.

Comment: I can provide a patch if you manage to work out how to open an image viewer from Cygwin on Windows (unfortunately I don't have Windows so I cannot test it myself). Please get back to me once you managed to make it work and then I'll post a patch.

Comment: I tried searching for the path on `image viewer`, but failed: do you know `image viewer`'s path?

Comment: No, but I found a post that seems to imply that `cygstart` from Cygwin works similarly to `start` at the ordinary Windows prompt, so you could try `cygstart` as the image viewer. (Source: http://saltnlight5.blogspot.no/2012/12/cygwin-tips-open-anything-with-cygstart.html )